# PayPal Get Parent Transaction of Refund transaction

Tags: paypal

I'm getting the transaction response of a refunded transaction ('transaction_status='V')

from the transaction search api :

https://developer.paypal.com/docs/api/transaction-search/v1/

I use this GET

```
      curl -v -X GET https://api-m.sandbox.paypal.com/v1/reporting/transactions?start_date=2014-07-01T00:00:00-0700&end_date=2014-07-30T23:59:59-0700&transaction_id=5TY05013RG002845M&fields=all&page_size=100&page=1 \
-H "Content-Type: application/json" \
-H "Authorization: Bearer Access-Token"
```

Is there any chance to get the parent transaction of the refunded transaction?!

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Do a GET directly on the refund using the [Payments API](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/api/payments/v2/#refunds_get).

```
curl -v -X GET https://api-m.sandbox.paypal.com/v2/payments/refunds/XXXXXXX \
-H "Content-Type: application/json" \
-H "Authorization: Bearer Access-Token"
```

See `links` in the response